# const declaration javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola Estoy usando jimp para manipulacion de imagenes y funciona bien en un pc con Ubuntu, ahora quiero instalarlo en otra maquina pero sale un error al ejecutarlo aparentemente de jimp

el codigo de jimp que muestra error

```
'use strict';
const toBytes = s => [...s].map(c => c.charCodeAt(0));
const xpiZipFilename = toBytes('META-INF/mozilla.rsa');
const oxmlContentTypes = toBytes('[Content_Types].xml');
const oxmlRels = toBytes('_rels/.rels');
```

El error mostrado es

```
 /var/lib/cloud9/node_modules/jimp/node_modules
/@jimp/custom/node_modules/@jimp/core/node_modules/file-type/index.js:2

const toBytes = s => [...s].map(c => c.charCodeAt(0));
                  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> 

(/var/lib/cloud9/node_modules/jimp/node_modules
/@jimp/custom/node_modules/@jimp/core/dist/utils/image-bitmap.js:12:40)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Alguien sabe como funciona la siguiente declaracion???

```
const toBytes = s => [...s].map(c => c.charCodeAt(0));
```

gracias

Comment: Querrás decir gimp por otro lado estás usando node para compilar los binarios?